# Deploy Flask application from Git repository with gspread API client_secret.json

Tags: python, flask, heroku, gspread

I want to deploy a flask application on heroku and in the flask app I use the Google Sheets API with gspread. To authenticate you get a client_secret.json file which you need to insert to `ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name()`. As you do it, I saved all the variables from the json file as enviroment variables and get them like this:

```
def create_keyfile_dict():
    variables_keys = {
        "type": os.environ.get("SHEET_TYPE"),
        "project_id": os.environ.get("SHEET_PROJECT_ID"),
        "private_key_id": os.environ.get("SHEET_PRIVATE_KEY_ID"),
        "private_key": os.environ.get("SHEET_PRIVATE_KEY"),
        "client_email": os.environ.get("SHEET_CLIENT_EMAIL"),
        "client_id": os.environ.get("SHEET_CLIENT_ID"),
        "auth_uri": os.environ.get("SHEET_AUTH_URI"),
        "token_uri": os.environ.get("SHEET_TOKEN_URI"),
        "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": os.environ.get("SHEET_AUTH_PROVIDER_X509_CERT_URL"),
        "client_x509_cert_url": os.environ.get("SHEET_CLIENT_X509_CERT_URL")
    }
    return variables_keys

scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(create_keyfile_dict(), scope)
```

But then I geht the Error:

```
    with open(filename, 'r') as file_obj:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'client_secret'
```

Because gspread wants a file right there and not a dictionary which my function returns.
So the question is more or less (if there is no better way) how I should get the enviroment variables to a file which is only on heroku and not on GitHub and can be read by gspread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using the method that comes with `ServiceAccountCredentials` intended to read from the JSON credentials file that google sends you, you can make use of this method:

https://oauth2client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/oauth2client.service_account.html#oauth2client.service_account.ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_dict